# Cannot invoke 'pathForResource' with an argument list of type '(String, ofType: JSON.Type)'

Tags: ios, json, swift

I want a solution to the problem
errror:

> Cannot invoke 'pathForResource' with an argument list of type
>   '(String, ofType: JSON.Type)'

My code looks like this:

```
func parsejson() {
    let path : String?  = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("ooo", ofType: JSON) as String!

    // let jsonData =  NSData(contentsOfFile: path) as JSON!

    //  let readableJson = JSON(data: jsonData, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil)
}
```

Comment: What is `JSON` ? What is the value stored in it ?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_NfijT6mt6A

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method `pathForResource:ofType` has been implemented a long time ago before Swift was introduced. At that time the operating system used terms like `File Type` and `File Creator`

Actually it means `pathForResource:withExtension` like the signature of the URL related counterpart.

Anyway I recommend to use the URL related API

```
if let url = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("ooo", withExtension: "json") {
  let jsonData =  NSData(contentsOfURL: url)! // it's NSData not JSON
  let readableJson = JSON(data: jsonData, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil)
} else {
  fatalError("The resource does not exist")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have at least two errors here.

First, you try set `ofType`, that is `String?` type to `JSON` type. Looks like you use `SwiftyJSON` and it type from there. You need to convert it to `String` object.

Second, you can not be passed as a parameter the class type, you have to create some object of this class and then pass it.

Comment: i use SwiftyJSON liabery , "ooo" is file json in project  :)

Comment: The problem, is true for some people, I watched this video like me work 8:00  ,  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_NfijT6mt6A

Comment: @Aslamdodeen At this video to `ofType` set the string "json" like in answer from @vadian but not the type `JSON`